# Mocha test with many imports takes lots of time

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) test with many imports , those imports make the test time very long (I tried a dummy test without any imports and it took only few seconds)

Here is the structure of my test - `TestSpeed.test.js`

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
// many other imports ..

describe('Test Speed', () => {

    it('Test Speed 1 equals to 1', () => {
        expect(1).to.eql(1);
    });
});
```

And I'm running it with the command - `node mocha TestSpeed.test.js`.

Is there any way to keep those imports in a cache and make the test faster? Any other idea how to make the test faster would be acceptable too.

Comment: Imports are already cached, so importing the same module once or twice doesn't make any difference. The best thing you can do is mocking those imports so that their modules don't get loaded.

Comment: So after running one time `node mocha TestSpeed.test.js` is there a way to keep the instances of all the imports and the second time of this command will be faster ?